# Existence of solution for the PDE $p \frac{\partial f(p, q)}{\partial p}-q \frac{\partial f(p, q)}{\partial q}=g(p, q)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, linear-pde

Consider the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
p \frac{\partial f(p, q)}{\partial p}-q \frac{\partial f(p, q)}{\partial q}=g(p, q),\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
where $g$ is a flat function at the point (0,0).

Let $X$ denote the the vector field $p \frac{\partial}{\partial p}-q \frac{\partial}{\partial q}$. The equation $\star$ can be also written as 
$\mathcal{L}_Xf=g,$ where $\mathcal{L}_Xf$ stands for the Lie derivative of $f$ along the vector field $X.$

I need to prove that there exists at least one $C^\infty$ smooth solution to the equation $\star$ in some neighbourhood of the point $(0,0).$ I also want this solution to be flat at the point $(0,0).$

The method of characteristics doesn't really work in this situation since (0,0) is a singular point of the vector field $X.$
The characteristics of $\star$ are given by the level sets of the function $pq.$ So it is easy to find a smooth solution in the domain $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(p, q)|pq=0\}.$ For example, the initial data can be given as: $f(p, q)=0$ if $p=q$ or $p=-q$.

But it is unclear whether or not this solution can be extended to some neighbourhood of the point $(0,0).$

I was thinking about this problem for quite a while but with no success so far.

Comment: For example, with $g(p,q) = p^2 q^2$, $f(p,q) = p^2 q^2 \ln |p|$ is a solution in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, but it is not $C^\infty$ and I doubt that any solution for this $g$ can be made $C^\infty$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that's right but the function $g(p, q)=p^2q^2$ is not flat at the point (0,0).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function

Comment: What does flat mean?

Comment: @DeaneYang, "flat" probably means that all the partial derivatives of $g(p,q)$ (of any order) vanish at $p=q=0$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine, yeah, that's right.

Comment: @Ilia:  I notice that you haven't commented on my proposed solution, and I'm wondering if there's something about it that's not clear.  If you still have questions about the solution, I'd be happy to try to answer them.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: Yeah I've understood your solution and it is really nice approach. Also it turned out that in my research the function g is not an arbitrary flat function but a function of the form $g = \alpha(pq),$ where  $\alpha$ is a flat function of one variable. In this case everything is a little bit simpler, for example, the function $g$ is even for any $\alpha.$ 
But still, it is quite interesting that this statement is true for an arbitrary flat function.

Comment: @Ilia:  If you are satisfied with my answer, then you should consider marking it as 'accepted'.  The reason is that, if a question doesn't have an accepted answer, the MO algorithm periodically moves it back up in the rankings in order to call attention to it as an 'unsolved' problem.  Marking an answer as 'accepted' stops that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is 'yes, a smooth, flat solution $f$ exists when $g$ is smooth and flat'.

Here is one way to show this:  I'll first do the case in which $g$ is *even*, i.e., $g(-p,-q)=g(p,q)$ and, for convenience, I'll assume that $g$ is defined on the entire $pq$-plane. (See the remark at the end about the local case.)

Let $(u,v) = (p^2{-}q^2,\,2pq)$, and note that there is a (unique) function $\bar g$ on the $uv$-plane such that $g(p,q) = \bar g(u,v)$ and that $\bar g$ is smooth and flat at $(u,v)=(0,0)$.  I will look for a solution of the form $f(p,q) = \bar f(u,v)$.  By the Chain Rule, the equation $(\star)$ then becomes
$$
2\sqrt{u^2{+}v^2} \, \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial u} = \bar g,
$$
so 
$$
\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial u}(u,v) = \frac{\bar g(u,v)}{2\sqrt{u^2{+}v^2}}.
$$
The right hand side is smooth and flat at $(u,v) = (0,0)$, so one has a solution in the form
$$
\bar f(u,v) = \int_0^u \frac{\bar g(t,v)}{2\sqrt{t^2{+}v^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\,.
$$
This $\bar f$ is flat and gives a solution to the problem, in fact, the unique solution that satisfies $\bar f(0,v) = 0$.

In the general case, one can write $g = g_0 + g_1$, where $g_0$ is even and $g_1$ is *odd*, i.e., $g_1(-p,-q) = -g_1(p,q)$.  So, to finish, by the linearity of the equation, it only remains to solve the equation when $g$ is odd.  This can be done by using the above solution on the half-planes $p>0$ and $p<0$ and being a little careful about the matching.  However, the right way to think about it in the odd case is that $\bar g$ is actually a section of a nontrivial flat line bundle over the punctured $uv$-plane, and the above integral is then taken using parallel translation in the flat line bundle along segements of the form $\sigma(t) = (tu,v)$ for $0\le t\le 1$, thereby yielding a section $\bar f$ of this nontrivial line bundle over the punctured $uv$-plane.  This defines a solution $f(p,q)$ of the equation on the punctured $pq$-plane that is odd and that vanishes to infinite order at $(p,q)=(0,0)$, i.e., it is a flat smooth solution, as desired.

For the local problem, one just assumes that $g$ is defined on an open neighborhood defined by $|p^2+q^2|<\epsilon^2$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and the line integrals in the formula will then still work to give the desired solution $f$ on the same neighborhood.

**Added remark:** It's probably worth pointing out that the above result can be applied to prove that the equation $(\star)$ can be solved for a smooth $f$ for a given $g$ if and only if $g$ is smooth and all of its 'balanced partials' (e.g., $g$, $g_{pq}$, $g_{ppqq}$, $g_{pppqqq}$, etc.) vanish at $(p,q) = (0,0)$.  This can be done using the above result plus the theorem that any formal Taylor series is the actual Taylor series of some smooth function.